# Game of life java new frame is not as it should be

Tags: java, conways-game-of-life

trying to create a Conways Game of life, but apparently the shapes are not like they have to be. Perhaps someone can help me find the issue.

For example the glider :

```
- X - - - - 
- - X X - - 
- X X - - -
- - - - - -
```

becomes this

```
- - X X - - 
- X - - - - 
X X X - - - 
- X X X - -
```

but should be like this :

```
- - X - - -
- - - X - -
- X X X - -
- - - - - -
```

And my code looks like this

```
public Frame(int x, int y) {

     setWidth(x);
     setHeight(y);

     if (x<1)
         frame = null;
      else if (y<1)
         frame = null;
      else {

       frame = new String [x][y];

         for (int i=0; i<frame.length; i++) {
            for (int j=0; j<frame[i].length; j++) {

               frame [i][j] = DEAD;
            }
         }
      } // else
   } // construktor


 public Integer getNeighbourCount(int x, int y) {

    Frame cell = new Frame(getHeight(), getWidth());
    int counter = 0;

    if(frame[x][y].equals(ALIVE))
    {
        counter = counter - 1;
    }
    for(int i=x-1; i<=x+1;i++){

        if(i<frame.length && i>0){

            for(int j=y-1; j<=y+1;j++){

                if(j<frame[i].length && j>0){

                    if (frame[i][j]==ALIVE) {
                        counter++;

                    }

                }
        }
        }
    }

    return counter;

}



public Frame nextFrame() {

    // Returns next frame


    Frame cell = new Frame(getWidth(), getHeight());
    //cell.frame = new String[getWidth()][getHeight()];

    for(int i = 0; i < frame.length; i++){
        for(int j =0; j <frame[i].length;j++){

            int n = getNeighbourCount(i,j);

                if(cell.frame[i][j]==null) {

                    cell.frame[i][j] = DEAD;
                }
               if (cell.isAlive(i, j) && n < 2 || n > 3) {
                   cell.frame[i][j] = DEAD;
               }
               if (cell.isAlive(i, j) && n == 3 || n == 2){
                   cell.frame[i][j] = ALIVE;
               }
               if(!cell.isAlive(i, j) && n == 3) {         
                   cell.frame[i][j] = ALIVE;
               }
               if(cell.isAlive(i, j) && n > 3){

                   cell.frame[i][j] = DEAD;
               }

               frame[i][j] = cell.frame[i][j];
        }

        }

    cell.toString();
    return cell;
}

    `
```

Full code http://pastebin.com/LMwz724H

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: i put the code in http://pastebin.com/LMwz724H because its too long

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are changing the values in frame[][] before you have finished calculating all the new values.

This line is the problem, because it occurs inside the loop:

```
frame[i][j] = cell.frame[i][j];
```

You need to have 2 arrays: frame[][] and nextframe[][]. As you iterate across the array, calculate the next state of each cell in the frame based on the current state (and neighbour's states), as you are doing, and store the new state in nextframe[][]. Then once you have calculated all the new states, copy the entire contents of nextframe[][] into frame[][].

Edit: assuming that cell.frame[][] is your nextframe[][], this code looks suspicious:

```
if (cell.isAlive(i, j) && n < 2 || n > 3) {
    cell.frame[i][j] = DEAD;
}
```

It is checking if the cell is alive in the next frame instead of the current one. Should it be this?

```
if (isAlive(i, j) && n < 2 || n > 3) {
    cell.frame[i][j] = DEAD;
}
```

Likewise for the other rules.

Also, why do you have this line in getNeighbourCount(), when you never use the cell variable in the function?

```
Frame cell = new Frame(getHeight(), getWidth());
```

Comment: `frame[i][j] = cell.frame[i][j]; ` putting it outside for loop didnt do the trick output is a bit different but still wrong, yeah these lines looked suspicious thank you.